# How to display process title by ps?

Tags: ps

As per [setproctitle(3)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setproctitle&sektion=3), the process title appears on the `ps` command. But after looking up the [ps(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2013.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports), I still have no idea how to display it by `ps`.

Comment: option `-o comm` will not give expected result ?

Comment: As @Archemar wrote : Issue ps -eo args,comm,command and observe the misc ways to display the process name. I bet that the second column displays what you wish.

Comment: @Archemar and @MC68020 Now I figure out it. The process title is just displayed by option `-o cmd`...

Comment: Many things can be learned by reading the fine manual. But it should be done on last resort…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `setproctitle()` indeed modifies the `argv[0]` of the calling process, so the **process title** can be displayed by `ps -o cmd`.